# How to run TestNG Scenario once per appended Tag?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber, testng

I'm trying to run some Scenarios based on the attached Tags. For example the code below should execute the same Scenario twice, once for `@tag1` and once for `@tag3`. `@tag1` should open a Chrome browser and `tag3` should open a Firefox browser.

When I execute the code only `@tag3` gets executed. Is it possible to implement what I want to achieve using Java and TestNG?

```
  @tag1 @tag3
  Scenario: I want to find an article on Wikipedia 1
    Given The user opened the Wikipedia Homepage
    And The user clicked on the Common link
    Then The user should be on the Common page
```

Comment: Why cannot you use scenario outline? And please share your runner class also.

Answer (score 0):

Please use scenario outline as @nandan said,

```
Scenario Outline: eating


Given there are <browser> of cucumbers
  When I login <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | browser| eat | left |
    |    chrome |   5 |    7 |
    |    firefox |   5 |   15 |
```